# Crystal Reports for VS 2010 Chart Legend/Labels

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, label

Real simple question that I can't seem to find an answer to guys. How to I change the labels associated with charts in the version of crystal for Visual Studio 2010? Or can I?

I always end up with the labels showing the field name from my data source or like @sum..

So my question is how do change these in the version of crystal I am using? Or am I going to have to wing it and color fill some boxes and use text objects?

VS2010 version :10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Crystal:13.0.5.891

Answer (score 1):

In Crystal Reports, run the report. In preview mode, do a right click on the
chart itself, and then go to "Chart analyzer". This will take you into a
designer mode of the chart. By selecting the axis title, you can open it up
and modify the content.

I haven't done this in the .NET environment, but everything else I've done
in the .NET Crystal Reports Designer has been the same.

Or, a bit of a hack, but you could alter the data source view/proc presumably to give alias's to your variables & fields?

I admit, not the ideal answer but it should work.

Comment: That is my fundamental issue with googling this problem. I'm working in VS, not in crystal. I can preview the report but I cannot follow the first of your suggestions. The second suggestion has crossed my mind, I wanted to avoid doing anything too strong handed till I knew for certain that I could or could not change the label.

Comment: It's going to be difficult given you are doing it in VS. Agreed, I would be reluctant to change the proc/view as this is a really ugly way of doing it IMO.

If you do figure it out be sure to post here!

Comment: Thank you for your help Alec, so far the only way I've seen it done other than changing the datasource is to DIY it on the report, if of course the points in your legend do not change. And to change the text associated with it I'm changing the labels in code. That's about one of the only solutions I've seen to not having the full version.